# How to change backcolor of controlBar in <video>

Tags: css, html

Anyone know how change background-color of ControlBar in `<video>` tag.

Same attach image.

[image: Same this]

Edit: Sorry .. I forgot post code:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" style="width:100%;height:100%;" controls="controls" poster="<?php echo $sermon->getImagen(); ?>">
  <source src="<?php echo $sermon->getVideoHd($GLOBALS['LANGUAGE']); ?>" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We don't need the PHP but we do need your CSS.

Comment: It is exactly what I need . No such change css, I try CSS => video {background -color: green} does not work.

Comment: @j08691 the php code only sets the src parameter so it doesn't matter actually. The css wouldn't help neither because the video controls are not really 'styleable'. For PPeter you should probably look for a tutorial how to create custom VideoPlayer controls. There are several on the web.

Answer (score 0):

you can't, you have to remove the `controls` attribute and than create your own custom controls, see this detailed guide: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html